# Strand specific tophat/cufflinks

Tags: bioinformatics

I have a strand-specific RNA-seq library to assemble (Illumina). I would like to use TopHat/Cufflinks. From the manual of TopHat, it says,

"--library-type TopHat will treat the reads as strand specific. Every read alignment will have an XS attribute tag. Consider supplying library type options below to select the correct RNA-seq protocol."

Does it mean that TopHat only supports strand-specific protocols? I use option "--library-type fr-unstranded" to run, does it mean it runs in a strand-specific way? I googled it and asked the developers, but got no answer...

I got some result:

[image]

Here the contig is assembled by two groups of reads, left side are reverse reads, while right side is forward. (for visualization, i have reverse complement the right mate)

But some of the contigs are assembled purely from reverse or forward reads. If it is strand specific, one gene should produce the reads in the same direction. It should not report the result like the image above, am I right? Or is it possible that one gene is fragmented and then sequence independently, so that happenly left part produce reverse reads while right part produce forward reads? From my understanding, the strand specificity is kept by 3'/5' ligation, so should be in the unit of genes.

What is the problem here? Or did I understand the concept of 'strand specific' wrongly? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tophat/Cufflinks are not for assembly, they are for alignment to an already assembled genome or transcriptome. What are you aligning your reads to?
Also, if you have strand specific data, you shouldn't choose an unstranded library type. You should choose the proper one based on your library preparation method. The XS tag will only be placed on split reads if you choose an unstranded library type.

Comment: Cufflinks IS for de novo transcriptome assembly! Check http://cufflinks.cbcb.umd.edu/

Comment: It takes aligned reads though, which means you need a genome sequence. Perhaps our use of the term de novo is different. You can discover novel things with Cufflinks, but for true de novo assembly, you need to be able to start from the actual fastq reads, not aligned reads.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a *de novo* assembly of your transcriptome you should take a look at assemblers (not mappers) like

- Trinity
- SoapDeNovo
- Oases....

Answer (score 0):

Tophat can deal with both stranded libraries and unstranded libraries. In your snapshot the center region does have both + and - strand reads. The biases at the two ends might be some characteristics of your library prep or analytical methods. What's the direction of this gene? It looks like a little bit biased towards the left side. If the left hand-side corresponds to 3' end then it's likely that your library prep has 3' bias features (e.g dT-primed Reverse transcription) The way you fragment your RNA may also have effects on your reads distribution. 
I guess we need more information to find the truth. But we should also keep in mind that tophat/cufflinks may have bugs, too.